# Cython: How to declare default values in pxd files

Tags: python-2.7, cython, default-value

I have a function I'd like to abstract into an importable module:

```
cdef list generate_random_vectors(int num_vectors, int length, float scale=1):
    cdef list return_list
    np.random.seed()
    return_list = []
    for n in range(num_vectors):
    return_list.append((1 - 2 * np.random.rand(length)) / scale)
    return return_list
```

To put this in a module, I have to define it in the pxd file.

When I try this:

```
cdef list generate_random_vectors(int num_vectors, int length, float scale)
```

I get the error: *Function signature does not match previous declaration.*

When I try this:

```
cdef list generate_random_vectors(int num_vectors, int length, float scale=1)
```

I get the error: *Expected ')', found 'INT'*

Answer (score 6):

Found it. The syntax is different in pxd files.

I need to use:

```
cdef list generate_random_vectors(int num_vectors, int length, float scale=*)
```